# MongoDB: Using 'c-driver' to find a document with $gte of 1

Tags: mongodb, gcc, bson, mongo-c-driver

I am trying to do something that should be pretty simple, but I am obviously doing something way wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

I know the `_id` of the document and I just want to verify that it's `available_uses` is `$gte 1`

Simple Document Sample:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("572f4d6f6d210e5c2d60cc41"), 
"invite_data" : "something useful here", 
"available_uses" : NumberInt(25), 
}
```

I have tried the following BCON but it does not work.  I am able to compile without any errors, but when I run it, the app dies as soon as the `query` line is set so obviously there is something wrong in that structure.  No errors, just app exits.

```
query = bson_new ();
bson_oid_t oid;
bson_oid_init_from_string (&oid, invite_id);

query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid),
    "{",
        "available_uses",
            "{",
                "$gte",  BCON_INT32 (1)
            "}",
    "}");   

// Find the document
cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many `{` & `}`.  Once again it is the sad issue that online documentation pointing you in the wrong direction.

Either way the correct codes are:

```
query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid),
    "available_uses", 
        "{",
            "$gt", BCON_INT32 (1),
          "}");
```